# How to send multiple row value submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I get the values from same row, but many values with `fetch array`. I did it, but with buttons, as many as how many values there are. If I have 5 rows, then I should have five submits, but I want one submit button.

Here is my code:

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("select * from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
        $myrow2= mysql_fetch_array($result2);

<form action="priceupdatetes.php" method="post">
<?php


do {
    echo <<<here

   <td><input name="etiket[$myrow2[id]]" type="text" value="$myrow2[etiket]"/></td>
   <td><input name="pricestandart[$myrow2[id]]"  type="text" value="$myrow2[pricestandart]"/></td>
   <td><input name="number[$myrow2[id]]" type="text" value="$myrow2[number]"/></td>
   <td><input name="totalunper[$myrow2[id]]" type="text" value="$myrow2[totalunper]"  disabled="disabled"/></td>
   <td><input name="discount[$myrow2[id]]" type="text" value="$myrow2[discount]"/></td>
   <td><input name="totalwithper[$myrow2[id]]" type="text" value="$myrow2[totalwithper]" disabled="disabled"/></td>





  </tr>

here;


}

while($myrow2= mysql_fetch_array($result2)) ;

?>

<input NAME="id[]" TYPE=hidden value="<?php foreach($myrow2[id] as $mid) {print $mid;} ?> "/>   

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/><br> 
</form>
```

HERE is **UPDATEPAGE.php**:

```
if (isset($_POST['etiket'])) {$etiket = $_POST['etiket']; }
if (isset($_POST['pricestandart'])) {$pricestandart = $_POST['pricestandart'];}
if (isset($_POST['number'])) {$number = $_POST['number']; }
if (isset($_POST['discount'])) {$discount = $_POST['discount']; }
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {$id = $_POST['id']; }

$totalunper=$pricestandart*$number;
$percent=$discount/100;
$totalwithper1=$totalunper*$percent;
$totalwithper=$totalunper-$totalwithper1;

foreach($id as $team_id)
{

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE price SET etiket='$etiket[$team_id]',pricestandart='$pricestandart[$team_id]',number='$number[$team_id]',totalunper='$totalunper[$team_id]',discount='$discount[$team_id]',totalwithper='$totalwithper[$team_id]' WHERE id='$team_id'");  }
```

How can I get values with different `id`'s and update them?

Comment: name="etiket[$myrow2[id]]" is array, you should get it with $_POST['etiket'][0]

Comment: if i have three values in array what can i do?  .i should write it as  $_post['etiket'][o], $_post['etiket'][1] $_post['etiket'][2]  ? like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input NAME="id[]" TYPE=hidden value="<?php foreach($myrow2[id] as $mid) {print $mid;} ?> "/>
```

is wrong. $myrow2[id] is not an array. Inside your while-loop, you should add:

```
<input NAME="id[]" TYPE="hidden" value="$myrow2[id]"/>
```

Comment: Thank u very much i didnt have to put it out of while loop. u fixed my problem thank u again